# pass pointer to 2D VLA as a function parameter that fills row vector in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I have a global `char *` which, at run-time, redeclare as a pointer to a 2D array declared as this [way](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2014/09/08/dont-use-fake-matrices/):

`char (*A)[N][M] = malloc(sizeof(char[BUF_16][N][M]));`

Then I read a file into my matrix of strings `A` with the function `read2mat` which uses the subroutines `tokenizer2D` and `removeEOF`, here is the code:

```
void removeEOF(char *s)
{
    char *newline = strchr( s, '\n' );
    if ( newline )
        *newline = 0;
}

void tokenizer2D(char *s, const char *delimiter, char *rowVec)
{
  char *saveptr; 
  char *token = strtok_r(s, delimiter, &saveptr);
  int j = 0;
  while (token)
    {
      printf("token: %s ", token);
      strcpy(&rowVec[j], token);
      token = strtok_r(NULL, delimiter, &saveptr);
      j++;
    }
  fputc('\n', stdout);

}

void read2mat(char filename[], const char delim[], int nrows, int ncols, int maxStrSize, char (*mat)[nrows][ncols])
{
  
  ncols = fmax(ncols, 1);
  // open the file for reading
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
      
  // make sure the file opened properly
  if(NULL == f)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file: %s\n", filename);
      return;
    }

  char linea[maxStrSize];
   
  int i=0;
  while (fgets(linea, maxStrSize, f) != NULL)
    {
      removeEOF(linea); // elimina '\n' del string
      tokenizer2D(linea, delim, &mat[i][0]);
      linea[0] = '\0';
      i++;
    }
  fclose(f);
}
```

Then I call it this way:
`read2mat(myfile, delim, N, M, BUF_32, A);`

Although in the `tokenizer2D` the function correctly prints the tokens read from each line I haven't been able to read them correctly into each element of `rowVec`, probably due to bad indexation.

Comment: `char (*A)[N][M] = malloc(sizeof(char[BUF_16][N][M]));` --> `char (*A)[M][BUF_32] = malloc(sizeof(char[N][M][BUF_32]));` ?

Comment: @ BLUEPIXY thanks, but that gives segfault.

Comment: [sample code](http://ideone.com/47i5ak)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY many thanks, please post it as an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
char (*A)[M][BUF_32] = malloc(sizeof(char[N][M][BUF_32]));
...
void read2mat(char filename[], const char delim[], int nrows, int ncols, int maxStrSize, char (*mat)[ncols][maxStrSize])
```

or

```
void read2mat(char filename[], const char delim[], int nrows, int ncols, int maxStrSize, char mat[nrows][ncols][maxStrSize])
```

call `read2mat(myfile, delim, N, M, BUF_32, A);`